# Open file to run x time - linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want to create x instance of a *.sh file. By exemple instad of open x terminals and enter ./*.sh in everyone, I want to open then open autmatlicly all doing the same "*.sh" file run.
Any way to do this?

I want all to work in same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gnome-terminal's `--command` option to achieve this. To get 20 terminals running the script in `/home/mtak/script.sh`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20)
do
  gnome-terminal --command=/home/mtak/script.sh &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

use any method to execute in the background, like `for i in $(seq 1 20); do nohup ./sh& done` (redirects output to nohup.out)